# How to represent spaces in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

How to represent the space inside this statement:

```
C:\\Program Files
```

so that I can put it inside my code properly. I suspect that my program does not work, because of the 'missing' char :(

I want to declare like this:

```
static char Log[256] = "C:\\Program Files\\Mywork\\text.txt";
```

This one does not work too:

```
      SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
  info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  info.lpFile = _T("C:\\Program Files\\Mywork\\iecapt.exe");
```

I am currently using visual studio to compile this. It can compile, but when running, it give error could not find the iecapt.exe.

Comment: A tip - if you are trying to reference Program Files - this might make more sense: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx

Comment: What function are you calling with this as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the space, it is the backslashes.  Try this:

```
static char Log[256] = "C:\\Program Files\\Mywork\\text.txt";
```

Otherwise the backslashes mean "interpret the next character according to the C string escaping rules, where "\t" for example means TAB.

The @"literal string" syntax suggested in another answer might work too, but I don't think it's standard outside of Windows.

Comment: OK, so you applied my fix but you still have a problem?  Are you sure the file you're trying to execute actually exists?

Comment: It exist. But somehow my program still could not find it. It give the path error.

Comment: You should see the link that Daniel A. White included in his comment, and not refer to Program Files by hard-coded path anyway.  :)  That said, what happens if you put two backslashes before the space, like "Program\\ Files"?

Answer (score -1):

@"my string here"

@ signifies a 'verbatim' string

should work!